# Angular Js service returns function/object?

Tags: angularjs, return, angularjs-service, angularjs-provider

As per the angular js [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#service)

service(name, constructor);
name : name
constructor : An injectable class (constructor function) that will be   instantiated.

```
Internally :
{
  $get: function() {
    return $injector.instantiate(constructor);
  }
}
```

> It could be concluded from the angular docs that service treats the
>   2nd argument passed as a constructor and provider creates an instance
>   through $injector and returns through $get. So whenever we will inject
>   the service in any of our module functions(controllers , directives
>   etc) it should return the newly created object which is Singleton
>   offcourse.

Now the problem comes here if I define my service like these ways.

```
1. _app_user_content.service("MyService" , function(){
        this.Message = "Greetings!";
    });  //returns object when injected.
2. _app_user_content.service("MyService" , function(){
        this.Message = "Greetings!";
        return "123"
    }); // returns object  when injected.
3. _app_user_content.service("MyService" , function(){
        this.Message = "Greetings!";
        return function(){}
    }); //returns function(){}  when injected. Doesnot return object
```

Why does the third case return a function?

Answer (score 3):

This is a JavaScript thing, more than an angular thing.

What an angular `service` does is basically use your function as a constructor by doing `new SomeObject()`, `SomeObject` being the function you defined in the second argument (important to note that in JavaScript functions are objects).

If your function returns nothing or a primitive value, the constructor will ignore your return value and instead return whatever you've set on the scope (this) of that function. If, however, you return an object, it seems the constructor will return that object instead. (Thanks @ajaykumar)

Try this in browser console...

```
function potato() {this.yummy = true; return function() {};} 
function tomato() {this.yummy = true;}
console.log(new potato());
console.log(new tomato());
```

You should see potato return `function () {}`.

You should see tomato return `{yummy: true}`.

For constructor functions such as this, I would recommend returning nothing.

If however you were to use angular's [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe) method, you will find that instead of doing `new SomeObject()` angular will do `return SomeObject()`, in which case you want to return an object with any functions / parameters you want to expose in your service.

More info on the JavaScript `new` keyword, prototypes and constructor functions [here](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword).

Comment: Your answer is pointing correctly to javascript syntactical fundamentals.
Further investigating, I could conclude that if the function returns javascript primitives it returns the newly created object. However if the return statement includes other than primitive types it simply assigns the return statement and does not create an object.